# IntelliJ IDEA 13.1.2 javadoc and tabs

Tags: intellij-idea, tabs, javadoc

I hate to ask such simple questions, but nothing I found so far helped me...

So, I've recently started using IntelliJ instead of Eclipse and there are 2 things that really bothers me...

1.) size of javadoc popup window - ok, so I finally get this little guy to pop-up whenever I need it, but it's so small I have to use scroll every single time... and that's pretty anoying when I'm working with unknown libraries...

2.) tabs == spaces - maybe some of you like this, but I don't... Eclipse was treating tabs as tabs and not spaces... I tried to change settings but with no result... or is that maybe connected with project I'm working on? (meaning, if, at the start of a project, setting were such that tabs == spaces and now changes are not applied to it)

Sorry for stupid question but, as I said, nothing I found so far helped me...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1) Just resize the window with your mouse. It will retain the size the next time it opens. You can also click on the gear icon in the upper right corner and adjust the font size. Again, it will retain the size on subsequent use.

2) I'm assuming you make the change to the "Use Tab Character" option on the "Tabs and Indents" tab for *all file types* and saved the Code Style. After that, you need to run the *Reformat Code* action (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or *Code > Reformat Code* from the menu or *Reformat Code* from the context menu (i.e. right-click) in The Project Tool window or Navigation Bar). IDEA retains the previous formatting (so spaces in this case) until you run a reformat on the project (or a part of it).

If you have multiple projects already created, for each one, you will need to go into *File > Settings > [Project Settings] > Code Style* and set the Scheme (and then do a reformat). While the Scheme definition is saved IDE wide, the scheme to use is set per project (which makes sense since an Apache Open Source project you are working on may have different code style requirements than the projects you do at work vs the ones you do for fun).

Finally, you will also want to go into *File > Other Settings > Default Settings > [Template Project Settings] > Code Style* and make sure your saved code style scheme (with the use tab option) is set so that new projects use that scheme when they are created.